# case insensitive in searchlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

Can Searchlogic search with case insensitivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to searchlogic [Read Me](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/blob/master/README.rdoc)

you can use

```
User.username_like("bjohnson")
```

and like is `case inesnsitive`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database configuration. For instance, postgres is case-sensitive by default and

```
User.username_like("bjohnson")
```

would not find Bjohnson.

sqlite is case-insensitive by default and would find Bjohnson, however.

Later versions of binarylogic's searchlogic has postgres-specific code that uses ILIKE to perform case-insensitive searches.

Any custom named scopes that you create will of course need to consider your db platform when case-sensitivity is a concern.